# MYSQL Group By Returning Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I am seeing a weird problem with MYSQL GROUP BY.

I have a query...

```
SELECT    schools.schoolregion, 
          Count(schools.schoolregion) AS regioncount, 
          ( 
                 SELECT Count(jobs_jobsubject) 
                 FROM   'jobs' 
                 WHERE  'jobs_createdDate' BETWEEN '$startofyear' 
                 AND    '$endofyear') AS regionjobstotal
FROM      'jobs' 
LEFT JOIN 'schools' 
ON        'jobs_schoolID'='SID' 
WHERE     'jobs_createdDate' BETWEEN '$startofyear' 
AND       '$endofyear' 
GROUP BY  'schoolRegion'
```

...in which I am attempting to total the number of job postings listed per region and group by region.  I have two tables, one with a list of schools and another with job information that has a column value that joins back to the school.  I need the region total, and the overall total of jobs within a time period (hence the sub query).

When I run this query, I get everything that I expect - except that I am getting a duplicate region listing in the returned results of the GROUP BY function.

For example, here is the table that I am getting but not sure why the duplicate for the Middle East.

```
 schoolRegion     regioncount   regionjobstotal
  Africa               1             38
  Asia                 6             38
  Middle East          20            38
  Middle East          11            38
```

I thought maybe there was an extra character or something, but I could not find/see anything different about the values within the tables - which for that column is being stored as type "text". Is there anything I can check for?  Is it something to do with the query?

Any help would be fantastic and much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, do I feel like a noob!!

When I adjusted the query to list the schools, there was only one school that was not included in the GROUP BY.  Initially when I looked at this hours ago, inline editing in PHPMYADMIN didn't show that there was a character return AFTER the text - so I wrote off that it was the text of the value being stored.  But when I checked the box to edit the row individually and not inline and went to that column value - low and behold - a carriage return!!!  Sometimes it's the little things like that which kill and humble me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the data is not ordered by schoolRegion.  I would add an `ORDER BY schoolRegion ASC` to your query to ensure that they are organized thusly. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It wasn't the solution, but I did include it with the query.

Comment: Ahh.. I see you found the issue.. I shouldn't have trusted you when you said you verified that the data was all consistent... :) :)  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

First, i do not think you can supply a child select statement as a column in your parent select statement "(SELECT COUNT(jobs_jobSubject)...".
Also since the where clause for your child and parent select are thesame, why not use a single select statement and get the count of both.

```
SELECT schools.schoolRegion,
COUNT(schools.schoolRegion) AS regioncount,
COUNT(jobs_jobSubject) AS regionjobstotal
FROM 'jobs' jb
INNER JOIN 'schools' sc ON jb.jobs_schoolID=sc.SID
WHERE 'jobs_createdDate' 
BETWEEN '$startofyear' AND '$endofyear'
GROUP BY 'schoolRegion'
```

Comment: The asker may need the `COUNT(jobs_jobSubject)` to not be multiplied by the number of matching rows in `schools`; so he'd still need a subquery (or at least a `COUNT(DISTINCT )`). But it doesn't look like the method he used is quite right either.

Comment: Thanks for the support and help from both of you.  I am curious though by what you mean by "But it doesn't look like the method he used is quite right either."  I am teaching myself all of this by scouring the internet for work around solutions to what I want to accomplish.  I want to make sure I'm doing it the right and most efficient way.

Comment: On reading your issue again, i will propose two possible solutions; try using an INNER JOIN instead of the LEFT JOIN and also try name your tables for effective join statement. I have edited the code to show you what i mean